# What locks are added when sql is executed in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

When I perform insert, delete, and update operations，What locks are added in the table?

i want to konw select insert delete update vacuum create index.

Comment: [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html) lists the locks taken for every statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ACCESS SHARE

Conflicts with the ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock mode only.
The SELECT command acquires a lock of this mode on referenced tables. In general, any query that only reads a table and does not modify it will acquire this lock mode.

#### ROW SHARE

Conflicts with the EXCLUSIVE and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes.The SELECT FOR UPDATE and SELECT FOR SHARE commands acquire a lock of this mode on the target table(s) (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other tables that are referenced but not selected FOR UPDATE/FOR SHARE).

#### ROW EXCLUSIVE

Conflicts with the SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes.The commands UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT acquire this lock mode on the target table (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any command that modifies data in a table.

#### SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE

Conflicts with the SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode protects a table against concurrent schema changes and VACUUM runs.Acquired by VACUUM (without FULL), ANALYZE, CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, and ALTER TABLE VALIDATE and other ALTER TABLE variants (for full details see ALTER TABLE).

#### SHARE

Conflicts with the ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode protects a table against concurrent data changes.Acquired by CREATE INDEX (without CONCURRENTLY).

#### SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE

Conflicts with the ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode protects a table against concurrent data changes, and is self-exclusive so that only one session can hold it at a time.Acquired by CREATE TRIGGER and many forms of ALTER TABLE (see ALTER TABLE).

#### EXCLUSIVE

Conflicts with the ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode allows only concurrent ACCESS SHARE locks, i.e., only reads from the table can proceed in parallel with a transaction holding this lock mode.Acquired by REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY.

#### ACCESS EXCLUSIVE

Conflicts with locks of all modes (ACCESS SHARE, ROW SHARE, ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE). This mode guarantees that the holder is the only transaction accessing the table in any way.Acquired by the DROP TABLE, TRUNCATE, REINDEX, CLUSTER, VACUUM FULL, and REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW (without CONCURRENTLY) commands. Many forms of ALTER TABLE also acquire a lock at this level. This is also the default lock mode for LOCK TABLE statements that do not specify a mode explicitly.

---

### How to check what lock I added in the table?

```
select * from pg_locks where relation='yourtablename'::regclass;
```

---

SQL corresponds to the lock [sql lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QhXM.jpg)

---

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/explicit-locking.html